# Update a Model in Django right before the backend select

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-managers

Before my Model in Django gets hydrated and filled with data, I want to update (alter) my model, save it back to the database and then go on the normal way.

My approach (not working) as now is this:

```
from django.db import models
from MyApp import models as m

class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # This is not evaluated to true although it should from my assumption:
        if (isinstance(self.model, m.MyObject)):
            # Here I want to take the internal key of
            # MyObject (maybe from the URL?),
            # Simply accessing self.model.internal_key does not work.

            # Then make an API call to an external server,
            # update my local object, save it back to db and proceed

        print(self.model) # Prints <class 'MyApp.models.MyObject'>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction if this is the correct approach and how I go on?

Comment: But your `model` is the *class* `MyObject` itself, it is *not* an instance of your `MyObject`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok, makes sense. Consider I access `/myapp/mymodel/123/change`, how do I update the database entry in `123` before Django loads the data and goes on to `ModelAdmin` / `Form` ?